# Complex Oracle Select Clause using unpivot

Tags: oracle11g

Please see my query below:

```
SELECT QUESTIONID, CORRECT_OPTION, CHOICE
FROM   QUESTION_RAW
    UNPIVOT (Choice FOR QUSTN IN (OPTION1 AS 'A', OPTION2 AS 'B', OPTION3 AS 'C', OPTION4 AS 'D'))
where QUESTIONID = 1
```

It gives me output as below:

```
Questionid CORRECT_OPTION CHOICE
---------------------------------
1         OPTION3         1 Day
1         OPTION3         2 Days
1         OPTION3         3 Days
1         OPTION3         None
```

Note: I want to display 'Y' instead of OPTION3 for the 3rd record and for rest I want to display 'N' like below

```
Questionid CORRECT_OPTION CHOICE
---------------------------------
1         N          1 Day
1         N          2 Days
1         Y          3 Days
1         N          None
```

Is it possible that I can do some calculation in select clause (like case) and show the output like above:

Comment: It's almost certainly possible.  You're going to have to tell us how to determine that the first, second, and fourth rows should be an N and the third row should be a Y.  Unless you want us to say that the third row is always Y and every other row is always N which seems unlikely (and problematic since you're not sorting the data).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You unpivot `for QUSTN IN (OPTION1 as 'A'` etc., which makes it difficult to write the proper `CASE` expression. Instead, unpivot `for QUSTN IN (OPTION1 as 'OPTION1', OPTION2 as 'OPTION2'` etc.

Then, instead of selecting `QUESTIONID, CORRECT_OPTION, CHOICE`, select `QUESTIONID, CASE WHEN CORRECT_OPTION = QUSTN THEN 'Y' ELSE 'N' END as CORRECT_OPTION, CHOICE ...`